# Null Pointer Exception when trying to delete an item in Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a long-time follower, first-time poster, so I hope I get this right. I'm trying to get into android-firebase development, and figured that the best way for that was to pick a project and try to find my way. I've been trying to develop a simple app for work (I'm a doctor) that'll allow our team to view brief progress notes about our in-patients, and will also allow us to post tasks needed to be performed on each patient. I've gotten most of it working, however, I'm stuck at one point. After I open a patient's record, A detail page loads, that includes a "comments" section, and a "tasks" section. Both of these are RecyclerViews containing many-to-one entries. The problem I'm facing has to do with trying to delete one of the "tasks" items when it's clicked (so it's removed from the list, and is no longer pending). I keep getting a Null Pointer Exception. The problem is, I'm not entirely sure if my code is correct. I'm still learning, so my code includes a lot of sections from different places that I've played with(I started with the android-firebase database sample from github, along with many other online sources), and re-written (after a lot of breaking and fixing) to get it working. Sorry for the long introduction. So, here's what I've got so far (not the complete code, just the sections I think are significant). I hope someone could help me out.

postDetailActivity.java

```
private static class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView dateView;
        public TextView bodyView;
        public ImageButton checkView;

        public TaskViewHolder(View itemView, final TaskAdapter mTaskAdapter) {
            super(itemView);

            dateView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_date);
            bodyView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_body);
            checkView = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check);
            checkView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Adapter Position:" + getAdapterPosition());
                    mTaskAdapter.removeItem(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }

private static class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private DatabaseReference mTaskReference;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Task, TaskViewHolder> mAdapter;

    private List<String> mTaskIds = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Task> mTasks = new ArrayList<>();


    public TaskAdapter(final Context context, DatabaseReference ref) {
        mContext = context;
        mDatabaseReference = ref;

        // Create child event listener
        // [START child_event_listener_recycler]
        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

                // A new task has been added, add it to the displayed list
                Task task = dataSnapshot.getValue(Task.class);

                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                // Update RecyclerView
                mTaskIds.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                mTasks.add(task);
                notifyItemInserted(mTasks.size() - 1);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

                // A task has changed, use the key to determine if we are displaying this
                // task and if so displayed the changed task.
                Task newTask = dataSnapshot.getValue(Task.class);
                String taskKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                int taskIndex = mTaskIds.indexOf(taskKey);
                if (taskIndex > -1) {
                    // Replace with the new data
                    mTasks.set(taskIndex, newTask);

                    // Update the RecyclerView
                    notifyItemChanged(taskIndex);
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onChildChanged:unknown_child:" + taskKey);
                }
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

                // A task has changed, use the key to determine if we are displaying this
                // task and if so remove it.
                String taskKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                int taskIndex = mTaskIds.indexOf(taskKey);
                if (taskIndex > -1) {
                    // Remove data from the list
                    mTaskIds.remove(taskIndex);
                    mTasks.remove(taskIndex);

                    // Update the RecyclerView
                    notifyItemRemoved(taskIndex);
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onChildRemoved:unknown_child:" + taskKey);
                }
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

                // A task has changed position, use the key to determine if we are
                // displaying this task and if so move it.
                Task movedTask = dataSnapshot.getValue(Task.class);
                String taskKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "postTasks:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to load tasks.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        ref.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
        // [END child_event_listener_recycler]

        // Store reference to listener so it can be removed on app stop
        mChildEventListener = childEventListener;

    }

    @Override
    public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_task, parent, false);
        return new TaskViewHolder(view, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Task task = mTasks.get(position);
        holder.dateView.setText(task.date);
        holder.bodyView.setText(task.text);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTasks.size();
    }

    public void cleanupListener() {
        if (mChildEventListener != null) {
            mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        }
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        mAdapter.getRef(position).removeValue();
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Error Log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(int)' on a null object reference
                  at com.hanykasem.omfsrounds.PostDetailActivity$TaskAdapter.removeItem(PostDetailActivity.java:606)
                  at com.hanykasem.omfsrounds.PostDetailActivity$TaskViewHolder$1.onClick(PostDetailActivity.java:451)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Like I said, I'm not really sure where the problem is, and I've tried a lot to get it sorted out, but couldn't. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not expert in firebase, but from your code I do not see are you assigning anything to your **mAdapter** field. That is why you are having NPE later on when accessing it in your **removeItem** method.

Example on how firebase adapter can be used:
http://www.coderefer.com/firebaseui-android-firebase-database/

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply ... but I've been trying to figure it out ... tried searching for it online ... but I'm not sure I can figure out how that's done .. can u be more specific?? Once again ... thank u

Comment: just added example where you can find how adapter instance can be created

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work (still trying to figure out where and how to implement it) ... I guess it needs to go in the TaskAdapter class ... maybe replace my existing TaskAdapter method ... will try to figure it out ... but atleast I know now which direction to go

Comment: Sorry ... I accidentally sent the post before saying Thank u ... so ... Thank you !!!